# Dropdown reset issues with IE7 works fine on FireFox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Hello Stackoverflow I have a simple form validation logic that doesn't seem to work on IE7 for some reason.

Basically I have two dropdown boxes and an input box. When the first dropdown box state changes the other dropdown and inputbox clears.

Current this logic seem to work on FF, Chrome but not IE7. Also the clearing of the input box works as expected on IE as well.

```
$('#names').change(function(){
    $('#rate').val("0");
    $('#amount').val("");
});
```

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the dropdown has an option with value 0 or ""?

Comment: the first option looks like this <option value="0">- -</option> also @pXL fixed that little typo :)

Comment: It should work fine, if not.. I am guessing that it has something to do with the markup. May be a missing `</option>`. I don't have IE 7 to test it out for you. Good luck.

Comment: markup looks fine, thanks for the help =) hopefully someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems IE requires you to add the null value in order to change it to the first element.

```
<option>--</option>
```

To

```
<option value="0">--</option>
```

Fixed the issue :)